# AD Authentication Login page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, active-directory, ldap

I am creating a helpdesk as a side project and have made a small login page with 'usernameTXT' and 'passwordTXT' textboxes.

I would like the username and password to authenticate against my AD server on my domain:

`domain - home.local
dc - home-serv`

I have tried all of the LDAP examples online with no luck. Could I be doing something wrong?

Please could someone help me to get ms site to authenticate with the domain? I would like all users to be able to login to the system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 Public Function Authenicate(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean
       Dim isValid As Boolean = False
       Try
       Dim de As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://local.home", username, password, _
            DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure Or _
            DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Sealing Or _
            DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Signing)
        de.RefreshCache()
        isValid = True
     Catch
     End Try
     Return isValid
End Function
```